# Importing and Exporting of data in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to import / Export multiple tables/Files in SSIS. Below are my cases and requirements.

Case 1 : I have n number of tables with different columns and data types, I need to loop through all the tables and export into excel / CSV files.

For Ex :

```
Table1 : Employee

EmpID   Empname
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

---

```
Table 2 :Department
Departmentid      DepartmentName
1                 HR     
2                 ADMIN
3                 SALES
```

---

```
Table 3 : Payroll

EmpId     DateOfJoining Salary
1         01/01/2012    15000
2         10/12/2014    20000
3         05/06/2006    50000
```

---

```
Table 4................table 100 etc.,
```

Now I want to loop all these 100 tables and need to export into excel/CSV files by using SSIS.

Case 2 : In the above examples I have data for all the 100 tables in Excel/CSV files and need to import into SQL server tables .

For these two cases(Import/Export) I want to use SSIS. Could you any one can suggest on this?

I know if the count of columns are same in 100 tables then it's possible to import/export. But count of columns are different in all the tables then How can we do importing / Exporting ?

Comment: If all 100 tables have different column numbers/data types then the only way I can see to deal with this is to set up 100 different data connections. However, if there are some tables with identical column numbers/data types then it might be possible to process these via a for .. each loop container.

Comment: SSIS seems like the wrong tool for this. Have you looked at bcp.exe?

Comment: You can execute bcp from SSIS if you really have to use SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try using BIML to automate your package creation.  [Copy data dynamically with bimlscript](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2011/05/31/copy-data-dynamically-with-bimlscript/)

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar situation and we have written a stored procedure that loops through sys.tables and creates a staging table for each relevant table.

You would have to use SQL system meta-data and dynamic SQL to read data definition (table name, column names) then write a dynamic SQL query to create the new staging table and then finally insert data into.

The SP is called from SSIS - and then the staging tables are manipulated in traditional SSIS job.  But the guts of that first step are done vis stored procedure.

Comment: Yes I know this way!!! But if you want to export multiple tables to excel/Csv files then how can be acheived